# Iterate through row's columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with 100 columns with not correlated names (ABC1, DA23, EE123 - there is no common pattern there).

I want to iterate through every row and every column in this table.

My current script:

```
BEGIN
   FOR single_row IN (
      SELECT *
      FROM MY_TABLE) 
   LOOP
      --iterate through columns of 'single_row'
      --for each nullable column do insert with real current column name and column value)
      --I assume each column is nullable except of ID
      INSERT INTO ANOTHER_TABLE VALUES (single_row.id, column_name, column_value);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

So for example, if MY_TABLE contains 2 rows:

```
ID|ABC1|DA23|EE123|...
1|123|456|789|...
2|321|654|987|...
```

After running my script, my ANOTHER_TABLE will contain:

```
MY_TABLE_ID|COLUMN_NAME|COLUMN_VALUE
1|ABC1|123
1|DA23|456
1|EE123|789
... other columns from row 1
2|ABC1|321
2|DA23|654
2|EE123|987
... other columns from row 2
```

How I can do this?

I'm using Oracle 11g

**EDIT**

@vkp provided great solution, but there is one more thing to solve. I don't want to specify all columns in `in` clause. I would love to use some kind of query there or * or anything else, just to not be forced to list all of them.

I have tried something like this:

```
select * 
from MY_TABLE t
unpivot (
   column_value for column_name in (select column_name 
        from user_tab_columns
        where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
        and nullable = 'Y')
) u
```

but it returns error:

```
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: If all you're concerned about is having to type out each column individually, why not just write a query that generates the columns. Hint: all_tab_columns contains a list of the columns for each table...

Comment: @Boneist I have tried it but it returns error

Comment: No, you have to run the query separately, then manually paste the columns you're interested in into the relevant clause in your unpivot query.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand something but what will change if I will store result of this query to variable and then pass this variable to unpivot `in` clause?

Comment: if you're always querying the same table and the table structure doesn't change, then you only need to specify the columns once. Therefore, generating the list of columns and copying them over only needs to happen once.
If, however, you want this to work against multiple tables (or the columns could change) then you'd need to use dynamic sql or the xml version in the answers below.

Comment: Also, I would ask why you're looping through your data and doing an insert, rather than just doing an insert-as-select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of `unpivot`.

```
select *
from my_table m
unpivot (column_value for column_name in (ABC1,DA23,EE123)) u
```

`null` values for any of the columns for an id won't be shown in the result.

If you have to include null values in the output, use the option `INCLUDE NULLS`.

```
select *
from my_table m
unpivot include nulls (column_value for column_name in (ABC1,DA23,EE123)) u
```

Edit: To include column names dynamically, use

```
DECLARE 
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
var_columns VARCHAR2(4000); --use clob datatype if the column names can't fit in with this datatype

BEGIN
SELECT LISTAGG(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name) 
INTO var_columns 
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name='MY_TABLE' AND column_name<>'ID';

sql_stmt:='select * from my_table m 
           unpivot 
           (column_value for column_name in (' || var_columns || ')) u';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
END;
/
```

Comment: great solution but incomplete. In your solution I need to specify the name of the columns `in (ABC1, DA23, EE123)` . I have 100 of columns, and can be more, so I don't want to write every single one there. How I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First option. With dynamic sql.

```
declare
         v_ctx  number;
         v_query  varchar2(500);
         v_total  NUMBER;         
         v_desctab    DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
         v_column_cnt     NUMBER;      
         v_value   varchar2(32767);
         v_result clob := '';
         v_rownum number := 0;
    begin
        v_ctx := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
        v_query := 'select * from user_objects where rownum < 100';
        dbms_sql.parse(v_ctx,v_query,dbms_sql.v7);     
        v_total := dbms_sql.execute(v_ctx);  
        DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(v_ctx, v_column_cnt, v_desctab);   
        for i in 1 .. v_column_cnt loop
          dbms_sql.define_column(v_ctx, i, v_value /* data_type varchar2*/, 32767 /* max_length*/);
        end loop;                   
   loop
        exit when dbms_sql.fetch_rows(v_ctx) = 0;
        v_rownum := v_rownum +1;
         for i in 1 .. v_column_cnt loop           
           dbms_sql.column_value(v_ctx, i, v_value);
           dbms_output.put_line(v_rownum||' - '||v_desctab(i).col_name||' - '||v_value);
         end loop;         
   end loop;
   dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_ctx);
   exception
        when others then
                dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_ctx);
                  raise;

   end;
   /
```

2nd option with xquery.

```
select t1.id,t2.* from xmltable('for $i in ora:view("<you_table_here>")/ROW
           return $i'
           columns id FOR ORDINALITY
           , row_value xmltype path'.'          
            ) t1
            ,xmltable('for $i in $row_value/ROW/* return $i' 
              passing t1.row_value as "row_value" 
               columns col_index for ORDINALITY ,
                  column_name varchar2(100) path 'name()',
                  column_value   varchar2(100) path 'text()'
             )  t2
```

Comment: I enjoy 2nd solution a lot more then 1st one. Result is again, almost correct. I want to exclude one column from input table. As my example shows, input table contains ID column which is excluded from result table

Comment: I know that 1st solution looks ugly but is better. If you want exclude something just add where clause in 2nd xmltable and find out something about `xquery flower`. 
`for $i in $row_value/ROW/* where $i/name() ne "<column_to_excude>" return $i` or other way `for $i in $row_value/ROW/*[name() ne  "<column_to_excude>" ] return $i`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using REF CURSOR.

I've tried this code and it's working at my end.

```
DECLARE
 query_2 VARCHAR2(1000);
 TYPE icur IS REF CURSOR;
 ic icur;
 col_val VARCHAR2(100);
 BEGIN
     FOR j IN
     (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = UPPER('MY_TABLE'))
 LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(j.column_name);
     query_2 := 'SELECT ' || j.column_name|| '  FROM MY_TABLE';
 OPEN ic FOR query_2;
 LOOP
     FETCH ic INTO col_val;
     EXIT WHEN ic%NOTFOUND;
     INSERT INTO ANOTHER_TABLE VALUES( j.column_name, col_val);
 END LOOP;
```

`END LOOP;
END;
/`

Comment: @ilovkatie did u try this solution. Does it work for you ?